# Sequelize findOne include gives empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

findOne with include doesn't work. It just give me no data. Deal data goes with Redemption [] <- here should be data

```
Deal.belongsTo(models.Redemption, {
      foreignKey: 'redemptionId',
      unique: true
    })


Redemption.hasOne(models.Deal, {foreignKey: {
        name: 'redemptionId',
        unique: true
    }})
```

Code where i'm trying to include Redemption

```
await Deal.find({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
        userId: req.user.id
      },
      include: [Redemption]
    }, {transaction})
```

So i'm expecting deal data with redemption ( included table ).

JSON

```
Redemptions:[] <--- empty
address:"62720 Rety, France"
business_name:"rwqrq"
category:null
cloudinary_key:"uzjwyyoritb5v81e3vba"
createdAt:"2017-09-27T14:09:30.469Z"
details:"trhrht"
end:"2017-10-03T21:00:00.000Z"
group_size:"—"
id:3
location:{type: "Point", coordinates: [50.792905, 1.7773789999999963]}
redemptionId:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redemption.hasOne(...)
```

generates a column on your 'deal' table called 'redemptionId'. So you can find Deal by using 'redemtionId'. But in your query, you are trying to find Redemption by using 'dealId'.That is the problem, I believe. If you really need Redemption, you have to make another query.

FYI: I am not expert but I am using sequelize recently. I would love to hear more from an expert. Thanks